# Contradiction for Roots of a Complex Polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

In y complex analysis course we learned a theorem about the roots of a complex, nonconstant, holomorphic polynomial.

That if $p(z)$ is nonconstant and holomorphic then $p$ has a root, i.e. for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ we have that $p(\alpha) = 0$.

But wouldn't $p(z) = z^2 + 1$, not have a root but is also holomorphic and nonconstant?

Comment: Are you sure that $p(z)$ don't have a root, now that you know complex number.

Comment: $z=i$ is a root

Answer (score 2):

$$p(z) = z^2 + 1$$ has two roots as promised by the theorem.

Both $ z=i$ and $z=-i$ satisfy $z^2+1=0$ so they are roots of $p(z) = z^2 + 1$

Probably you were expecting real roots.

Well, the theorem did not prove that the roots are necessarily real.